# Subnet slash 22 setup with 192.168.5.1 gateway

Tags: subnet, gateway

I am trying to enlarge my ip adresses subnet and id like to pass from a /24 to a /22. So i set the following : ip : 192.168.5.20 subnet 255.255.252.0 and gateway 192.168.5.1 . the problem is that everytime I try it makes the ips starting at 192.168.4.1 instead of 192.168.5.1 . What am i doing wrong??

Comment: Check your DHCP setup?

Comment: I dont think ot is a dhcp problem also here setting a /22 with gateway 192.168.5.1 it starts at 4.1  : http://cric.grenoble.cnrs.fr/Administrateurs/Outils/CalculMasque/

Comment: Use your DHCP to start allocating addresses from 192.168.5.2

Comment: Thanks! Why do you think it starts at 4 otherwise?

Comment: No idea..... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A netmask of 255.255.252.0 (=> /22) makes the first available address be 192.168.4.0 (the base net address), when given x.x.5.x - nothing strange there.

Comment: Thanks but why it starts at 4.1 and not 5.1??

Comment: DHCP handouts starts at the base (subnet/network) address +1, unless you define something else in the for DHCP. This is the lowest possible IP in your subnet, keeping the upper 22 bits as you wrote them - clearing the others, adding 1.